# image flashing when interacting with other element

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating this page where there are 4 image slides on a 2x2 orientation. Now I'm still pretty new to html and css, so I'm not sure which part of my code is causing this.

The css i used for the sliders are all the same, but the sliders on the right keeps flashing when i hover over an element. Here is the page that I'm working on http://website-testing.site88.net/Smile.html.

Sample of the code is below here:

```
    <input type="radio" name="slide1" id="S1_I1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="slide1" id="S1_I2">
    <input type="radio" name="slide1" id="S1_I3">
    <input type="radio" name="slide1" id="S1_I4">

<ul id="container">
    <li class="left"> Placeholder 
      <div class="slides_container"> 
        <div class="slides">
        <ul>
            <li><div class="img">
                  <img src="pic/pic_1.jpeg">
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="S1_I2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><div class="img">
                  <img src="pic/pic_2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="S1_I1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="S1_I3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><div class="img">
                  <img src="pic/pic_3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="S1_I2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                    <label for="S1_I4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><div class="img">
                  <img src="pic/pic_2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <label for="S1_I3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>  
    </li>
```

Any ideas what could have caused this?
Also this is the first time i created a website, so it may look ugly on other browsers, since I'm not sure how to make them look compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's causing it is this piece of code:

```
/* -webkit-columns: 2; */
-moz-columns: 2;
-o-columns: 2;
columns: 2;
```

You can find it in your `smile.css`  on the FIRST line inside the file.

Take it out and it won't flash anymore. 
BUT you will have to move things around a bit as it will slightly mess up the images positioning you have. In anyway, don't use `columns:2` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, been trying to figure out the problem, but how should i make it so its in a 2x2 grid now?

Comment: Well to be honest the html is really messy and not coded well. 
Also I noticed that the website is not fully responsive. 
So if your purpose is to learn, If I were you  I'd start with creating a fiddle to simplify what it is you're trying to do. 

You can create a fiddle here: fiddle.jshell.net
Notice on the left side you have a box with HTML,, and on the side CSS. 
Try to make a box and put two columns (one left and one right) inside the box. Then try to put the images or something else inside those columns. I'd say this is a good start!